# Angular-Scroll: same as example, but not working (Plunker)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular-Scroll (https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll) to simply scroll to an `<a>` link on the same page, but do it nicely and smoothly. When I couldn't get it to work, I made a super simple setup in Plunker.

**Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/w1GBTAjxtHL3H4LAuHoO

If you download the zip of the GitHub, there's an example I'm trying to do in the folder location `angular-scroll-master/example/container.html`. There's really nothing complex, the angular script is basically just finding the container id for the directive to use.

I cannot figure out why my page will not scroll.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="medium-6 columns" du-scroll-container="container">
    <a href="#junk" du-smooth-scroll="" du-scrollspy="">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div id="container" class="medium-6 columns" du-scroll-container="">
    <div id="junk">LINK JUNK HERE YAY!!</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('scrollDemo', ['duScroll']).
  controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var container = angular.element(document.getElementById('container'));
});
```

Comment: Open your browser console and look at errors. Script dependency loading order is  wrong in demo. Can't load plugins and code that are dependent on a library before the library is loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your plunker and it seems to be working now. Here is the [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/REH9zcyuuvbyVFYg59uC?p=preview).

The problem was that the container div is not the scrollable container that would be the `body` element to make it work as the scrollable element you can set the max-height of the container so that it will become the scrollable element or remove the `du-scroll-container="container"` atribute so that it will use the body as the scrollable element.

Comment: Thanks so much for the context, I moved the `du-scroll-container="container"` to another location in my original file and it started working.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was facing a similar no-scrolling issue and this answer helped me realize I have to put `du-scroll-container` on a different div... You have to be careful where it is located - if I get it correctly, it should in the container of the scroll-able content.